# Getting junk characters while printing word document in php

Tags: php, mysql, ms-word

I am tring to display word document on the screen which was already stored in mysql but i am getting junk charactes. below is the code

```
<?PHP
include ("db.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ordinary_clients ec WHERE ec.groom_id='43' AND ec.sno='5' ";
$sqlquery=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($rec=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlquery))
{
echo 'Name:'.$rec['name'];
echo $rec['data'];
}
```

The colum name data belows to longblob datatype.

Comment: longblob are used for storing the binary strings, i think that's the reason why you are getting junk value as an output.

Comment: The word document will have some content and image. if longblob is not the correct data type can u suggest something else?

Comment: if you are have images then longblob is the  perfect datatype but the output what you are getting is not junk data, it is an binary strings you need covert that binary string to actual data for that you can try with [Unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)

Comment: tried but it is not working

Comment: FWIW if this was a docx document then the document as a whole is a ZIP package of XML files. The picture will be in base64. The Word application is required to actually render the content as something meaningful (a document).